# GetBasicPersonalData returns error 570058: "Authentication failed. User account is not confirmed"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-permissions

I'm making a request to the Permissions Service's GetBasicPersonalData method in Sandbox mode. I am passing in an access token that was returned by the GetAccessToken method.

I receive the following error

```
570058: "Authentication failed. User account is not confirmed"
```

I did some Googling and it seems the reason might be that the user has to confirm their email address by actioning the email they receive from PayPal. The problem is I'm not receiving such an email. I've created two different PayPal accounts in the sandbox, clicked the "Confirm email address" notification, and neither has received the email.

If I'm correct that I need this email to proceed, why isn't it appearing? Does this function not work in the sandbox?

If the error I'm getting (570058) is not related to this email, how else might I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confirm PayPal sandbox account email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316743/confirm-paypal-sandbox-account-email)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using an account created through www.sandbox.paypal.com, I used a sandbox account I created through developer.paypal.com, which didn't need to be confirmed.