# Paypal sandbox account email confirmation

Tags: email, paypal, account

I have created a sandbox account on developer site. Everything was fine when the account country was from the list. Then I created another account by following the link in the "Create test account" site with a country that was not on a previous list. Its email is unconfirmed and I can't find a way how to activate it. Without it I can't accept payments from other test accounts. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confirm PayPal sandbox account email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316743/confirm-paypal-sandbox-account-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared, that I had to copy and paste the confirmation link, which can be found in the sandbox test accounts site in the notifications section. Silly me...

Comment: I can't find such a section in my sandbox account. Can you be more specific, please? Thank you!

Comment: See as well [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182051/getbasicpersonaldata-returns-error-570058-authentication-failed-user-account)

Comment: I cannot find the email if it is a business testing account. Personal account is ok.