# Confirm PayPal sandbox account email

Tags: email, paypal, sandbox

Same question as this: [Paypal sandbox account email confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355020/paypal-sandbox-account-email-confirmation) but it was not so easily resolved for me.

I can't confirm my sandbox email address, it says an email would be sent to my email address (which it wasn't) and I read elsewhere that it should be found in the "Test Emails" section at developer.paypal.com. I'm looking at [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/dashboard/email) ([updated link](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/)) and it's not there either.

Can someone point me to the correct place to find this confirmation email?

The reason I need to confirm my email address is I'm getting this error when trying to make a test payment to the sandboxed merchant account with a sandboxed personal account:

```
Rapids::Exception (N6Rapids5Tools13PimpExceptionE): Pimp RC: 3514
```

Apparently verifying the merchant email address fixes this.

Answer (score 13):

On Developer site is section Dashboard then Sandbox notifications - there are emails and sms from sandbox account, and also it catches confirmation emails which should go to your email...

I found it after one day of looking what's happend with email confirmations -.- .

Comment: Just some more clarification for people maybe as slow as me, https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/ is where you find the 'notifications' link (https://i.imgur.com/sEqQ5O3.png) with the confirmation email. Not  http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/settings/ which also has a 'notifications' link (https://i.imgur.com/YN5qkTJ.png)

Answer (score 8):

Turns out the answer was not to try manually create a sandbox account on the sandbox website, but to automatically create one at [developer.paypal.com > Applications > Sandbox Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/). This was much quicker and easier to do too!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Adapative Accounts API to create account (in the first place), put confirmEmail as TRUE in createAccountWebOptions (for registrationType = Web).. this way you wouldn't have headache of email confirmation, for new accounts.